# Input in ng-repeat not update even ng-model is changed

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have a table with input inside it to allow users edit the quantity of goods, the total values of all goods in the bill is calculated when user input the quantity via `ng-change`. In `ng-change`, i will check if the quantity is large than current stock, i will reset it to old value and do not update total values (plus show msg err etc.....). Everthing gone fine, but my only problem is I can not make the input update with the model.

```
<table st-table="goodsOfBillList" st-safe-src="sellDetailList" class="table table-striped">
<tr ng-repeat="row in goodsOfBillList" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="single" ng-show="!sellBillCtrl.isLoading">
    <td>
        <input id="quantity" ng-model="row.quantity" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
               placeholder="current stock : {{row.currentStock}}"
               class="form-control input-md" required="" type="number" min="1" max="{{row.currentStock}}"
               ng-change="updateTotal(row, '{{row.quantity}}')">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When i input an invalid value (50) like the picture below, quantity is reset back to previous value (5), but the input in the model doesn't update

```
$scope.updateTotal = function (row, oldVal)
{
    //because I set max value, if I input an invalid value, row.quantity become undefined
    //Checked by using alert()
    if(typeof row.quantity === "undefined") 
    {
        row.quantity = oldVal;
        alert(JSON.stringify(row));
        return;
    }
    //logic if valid value   
};
```

[image]

i am using input in smart-table, and the table inside a boostrap modal

Comment: Please read your post once! I think it is incomplete

Comment: Which information do you want to know more? My problem is similar to this : http://jsfiddle.net/HaiUit/tk7z7juf/

All i want is when the ng-model changed in code, the input text is updated too.

Comment: **1.** Check your fiddle, it is not working! Also when you are passing full **row** why do you pass **row.quantity**? **2.** update your post with the sample json. **3.** if possible create a working plunker..

Comment: 1. What do you mean "not working"?I just type a value < 20, and thee alert fire.
2. The row,quantity is the ortiginal value before change, I use it to revert row.quantity if user input an invalid value.

Comment: Create a plunkr of your problem which makes work easy.

Comment: model-options is on onBlur. Ensure you haven't the focus on your input when you check value on input.

Comment: I'm really confused now, despite finding out what cause the problem, I can not understand it.The code on plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/OsxmQxS6WMD5ZyyRgFnK working perfect, and it tell me what happened.

Line row.quantity = oldVal; in my project can not effect the st-safe-source, but in plunks it does. To make it work, i must iterate the st-safe-src and make change in it. Maybe i missing something, but it's too hard to find out.

Comment: @Silvinus, I've removed onBlur to check if it cause the problem, but not. The problem be cause variable "row" pass to updateTotal does not reference to the row in dt-safe-src